# How to display time taken (in the command prompt) for retrained object detection model to detect objects?

Tags: python, object-detection-api

I've managed to retrained SSD MobileNet for my own custom object detector. But I can't find ways to display the time taken for the SSD MobileNet to detect objects, in the command prompt. Any changes I need to apply to my current code?

I'm new to Python (and StackOverflow), and would appreciate it in advance for the guidance.

```
import os
import cv2
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import sys
sys.path.append("..")
from utils import label_map_util
from utils import visualization_utils as vis_util
from utils.label_map_util import load_labelmap as ll

MODEL_NAME ='xxxx_graph'

CWD_PATH = os.getcwd()
PATH_TO_CKPT = os.path.join(CWD_PATH,MODEL_NAME,'frozen_inference_graph.pb')
PATH_TO_LABELS = os.path.join(CWD_PATH,'training','object-detection.pbtxt')

NUM_CLASSES = 2
label_map = label_map_util.load_labelmap(PATH_TO_LABELS)
categories = label_map_util.convert_label_map_to_categories(label_map, max_num_classes=NUM_CLASSES, use_display_name=True)
category_index = label_map_util.create_category_index(categories)
detection_graph = tf.Graph()
with detection_graph.as_default():
  od_graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
  with tf.gfile.GFile(PATH_TO_CKPT,'rb') as fid:
    serialized_graph = fid.read()
    od_graph_def.ParseFromString(serialized_graph)
    tf.import_graph_def(od_graph_def, name='')
  sess = tf.Session(graph=detection_graph)
image_tensor = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('image_tensor:0')
detection_boxes = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_boxes:0')
detection_scores = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_scores:0')
detection_classes = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_classes:0')
num_detections = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('num_detections:0')

#REAL-TIME INPUT
video = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
ret = video.set(3,1000)
ret = video.set(4,800)
while(True):
  ret, frame = video.read()
  frame_expanded = np.expand_dims(frame, axis=0)
  (boxes, scores, classes, num) = sess.run(
    [detection_boxes, detection_scores, detection_classes, num_detections],
    feed_dict={image_tensor:frame_expanded})
  vis_util.visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array(
   frame,
   np.squeeze(boxes),
   np.squeeze(classes).astype(np.int32),
   np.squeeze(scores),
   category_index,
   use_normalized_coordinates=True,
   line_thickness=8,
   min_score_thresh=0.8)

  cv2.imshow('object detection', frame)
  if cv2.waitKey(25) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
   cv2.destroyAllWindows()
   break
```

Comment: Hi shiba, welcome to stackoverflow. Could you please tell us what's the desired output?

Comment: The desired output would be displaying the time taken to detect that particular class along with the score in the command prompt. However, it is not desired when it report that there is no object detected. I'm only interested in knowing the objects it detected and how fast it able to detect it.